# setting path variable via SSH to other user than root

Tags: ssh

I try to install node on my RPi using [this tutorial](http://joshondesign.com/2013/10/23/noderpi)

But when I type "node -v" to test it doesn't provide any output:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ node -v
```

whereas the complete path does:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ /opt/node/bin/node --version
v0.10.2
```

although my path variable is well set (via .bash_profile):

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ path
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/sbin
/usr/bin
/sbin
/bin
/usr/local/games
/usr/games
/opt/node/bin
```

I think it matters to precise I am doing all this stuff via SSH.

[EDIT]: 
When I am root, it works...

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# node -v
v0.10.2
```

How to make it work even when I am 'only' the user 'pi' ?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What about `node --version`?

Comment: @Gerben `node -v` and `node --version` are equivalent.

Comment: when you ssh, what does `whoami` give? You should be logged in as pi, so you should have the same path that you have when you're logged in "normally".  And what does `which node` give?

Comment: thks francis, whoami -> pi, and which node -> /usr/local/bin/node ... Unexpectedly, the day after I posted this question, it worked without any changes... so I really don't know what did the trick, but it works now. The only thing I could have done was a reboot of the pi, but I doubt I forgot to try it at first time... So I cannot really explain...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unexpectedly, the day after I posted this question, it worked without any changes... so I really don't know what did the trick, but it works now. The only thing I could have done was a reboot of the pi, but I doubt I forgot to try it at first time... So I cannot really explain, but you can try to reboot your pi.